# Gridview - Add Row Button Using Footer

Tags: vb.net, gridview, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for some help with a add row button, I am having a problem with the sub to insert the data.

This is the error I am receiving:

> Error1:   Method 'Protected Sub SqlDataSource2_Inserting(sender As
> Object, e As
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs)' cannot
> handle event 'Public Event Inserting(sender As Object, e As
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs)' because they
> do not have a compatible
> signature.    C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2012\Projects\Certificates\Certificates\WebForm1.aspx.vb  17  161 Certificates

html code:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Certificates.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="Laboratory" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LaboratoryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ShowFooter="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="AddRow" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Add" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address" SortExpression="Address">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Providence" SortExpression="Providence">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Providence") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtProvidence" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Providence") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ZipCode" SortExpression="ZipCode">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ZipCode") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtZipCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ZipCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country" SortExpression="Country">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Country") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone" SortExpression="Phone">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fax" SortExpression="Fax">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fax") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtFax" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fax") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GreatGrizzlyConnectionString1 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Laboratory] WHERE [LaboratoryID] = @LaboratoryID" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Laboratory] ([Name], [Address], [Providence], [City], [ZipCode], [Country], [Phone], [Fax], [Email]) VALUES (@Name, @Address, @Providence, @City, @ZipCode, @Country, @Phone, @Fax, @Email)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Laboratory]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Laboratory] SET [Name] = @Name, [Address] = @Address, [Providence] = @Providence, [City] = @City, [ZipCode] = @ZipCode, [Country] = @Country, [Phone] = @Phone, [Fax] = @Fax, [Email] = @Email WHERE [LaboratoryID] = @LaboratoryID">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="LaboratoryID" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Providence" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Providence" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ZipCode" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Country" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Phone" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fax" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="LaboratoryID" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my vb code:

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Private Sub GridView1_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles  Laboratory.RowCommand
    ' Insert data if the CommandName == "Insert"
    ' and the validation controls indicate valid data...
    If e.CommandName = "Insert" AndAlso Page.IsValid Then
        ' Insert new record...
        SqlDataSource2.Insert()
    End If
End Sub

    ' Sub to reference footer text cells and Insert them into new row in database
Protected Sub SqlDataSource2_Inserting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As  System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource2.Inserting
    ' Programmatically reference Web controls in the inserting interface...
    Dim NewName As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtName")
    Dim NewAddress As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddress")
    Dim NewProvidence As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtProvidence")
    Dim NewCity As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCity")
    Dim NewZipCode As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtZipCode")
    Dim NewCountry As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtcountry")
    Dim NewPhone As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtPhone")
    Dim NewFax As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFax")
    Dim NewEmail As TextBox = Laboratory.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmail")

    ' Set the ObjectDataSource's InsertParameters values...
    e.InputParameters("Name") = NewName.Text
    e.InputParameters("Address") = NewAddress.Text
    e.InputParameters("Providence") = NewProvidence.Text
    e.InputParameters("City") = NewCity.Text
    e.InputParameters("ZipCode") = NewZipCode.Text
    e.InputParameters("Country") = NewCountry.Text
    e.InputParameters("Phone") = NewPhone.Text
    e.InputParameters("Fax") = NewFax.Text
    e.InputParameters("Email") = NewEmail.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't post all you have without informations what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check here?

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?385892-RESOLVED-Adding-rows-to-GridView-programatically

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detail. I added the error I am recieving. I beleive the problem has to do with the: ' Sub to reference footer text cells and Insert them into new row in database